# Strange path separators on Windows

Tags: python, windows, filepath

I an running this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python      coding=utf8
#  test.py = to demo fault
def loadFile(path):
    f = open(path,'r')
    text = f.read()
    return text
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'D:\work\Kindle\srcs\test1.html'
    document = loadFile(path)
    print len(document)
```

It gives me a trackback

```
D:\work\Kindle\Tests>python.exe test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    document = loadFile(path)
  File "test.py", line 5, in loadFile
    f = open(path,'r')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'D:\\work\\Kindle\\srcs\test1.html'

D:\work\Kindle\Tests>
```

If I change the path line to

```
path = 'D:\work\Kindle\srcs\\test1.html'
```

(note the double \\) it all works fine.

Why? Either the separator is '\' or it is not, not a mix?

System. Windows 7, 64bit, 
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Checked - and all the backslashes appear correctly.

Comment: You can use forward slash path separators, even in Windows (or even DOS, for that matter). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character when the next character combination would result in a special meaning.  Take the following examples:

```
>>> '\r'
'\r'
>>> '\n'
'\n'
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>> '\c'
'\\c'
>>>
```

r, n, and b all have special meanings when preceded by a backslash.  The same is true for t, which would produce a tab.  You either need to A.  Double all your backslashes, for consistency, because `'\\'` will produce a backslash, or, B, use raw strings: `r'c:\path\to\my\file.txt'`.  The preceding r will prompt the interpreter not to evaluate back slashes as escape sequences, preventing the `\t` from appearing as a tab.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape backslashes in paths with an extra backslash... like you've done for `'\\test1.html'`.

`'\t'` is the escape sequence for a tab character.

`'D:\work\Kindle\srcs\test1.html` is essentially `'D:\work\Kindle\srcs   est1.html'`.

You could also use raw literals, `r'\test1.html'` expands to:

```
'\\test1.html'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use raw strings for Windows paths:

```
path = r'D:\work\Kindle\srcs\test1.html'
```

Otherwise the `\t` piece of your string will be interpreted as a Tab character.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` is an [escape character](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-are-escape-characters/) in Python. So your actual filepath is going to be `D:\work\Kindle\srcs<tab>est1.html`. Use os.sep, escape the backslashes with `\\` or use a raw string by having `r'some text'`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a raw string (prefix string with the r character), the os.path module may be helpful to automatically provide OS-correct slashes when building a pathname.

Answer (score 0):

[Gotcha — backslashes in Windows filenames](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) provides an interesting overview.

Comment: Link no longer exists.