# OS independently constructing paths

Tags: python

I have been using the following when joining paths in a python script I have been coding to allow for maximum compatability between Linux/Windows systems;

```
  path = join(dirname(__file__),'..','..','folder','destination')
```

It works perfectly on Linux, however when I now run this in Windows it is adding a double \\ instead of just the one?
I am sure I saw something that mentioned this somewhere before but I cannot find it now I have it happening to me. (e.g C:\program files\folder\) This is causing the script to error with a no such file or directory found.

EDIT:
And the reason that I couldn't find any solutions for this is because it was actually working all along, the logger module that output the log error actually added the double slashes, the error was related to a try catch I had used and so in actual fact the above line works perfectly for linux/windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange path separators on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928789/strange-path-separators-on-windows)

Comment: I did quite a bit. Sadly I didn't try the word separators, I was looking more specifically at path search queries which didn't give me any useful results

Comment: Also that link doesn't appear to relate to my query, that is related to strings but from what I understood of the join function I am using from os.path it is constructing the path for me and handling the slashes

Comment: No, it fully explains the "issue" you are seeing. Hint: Does the word "escape" have a special computer-related meaning?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the hostility? I appreciate what an escape character is but I am constructing the path through the join function, in that question you linked to one of the answers suggests using the join functionality to avoid any separator / escape character related issues which would suggest that my problem lies elsewhere. I have only come here to ask for assistance after trying to resolve this myself, if there is something obvious I am missing then please explain but there is no need for rudeness

Comment: You think it's rude to suggest that you actually do research, and understand the other answers here? There's nothing I can do for you.

Comment: No, I thought your tone in asking if the word escape has a special computer related meaning along with not reading and responding to my valid points. I clearly have a lack of understanding of the problem here but everything I have read indicates that using path avoids the issues encountered by using strings, as per the link you posted. I'm just trying to solve what I am assuming is something silly I must be doing :)

Answer (score 3):

[`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is probably what you have been looking for in the python docs.

Comment: That's what I am using in the above example

Comment: My bad mixing up languages right now... my first glance at the question suggested that you were using `string.join`.  Explicitly stating `os.path.join` may be helpful when all we have to go on is what you type ;)

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I was assuming I had done something silly and someone would spot it straight away as I couldn't find anything on the interwebs that explained it, turned out it was working all along, RE:my edit above.