# prefix and suffix to each line of a txt using python

Tags: python, text, line, prefix

I need to add some texts to a document like this:

Original document:

```
C:\listagem.txt

i love python  
macdonals hamburger  
yolo 4ever
```

I need to add a suffix and a prefix, so the result would look like this:

```
teste.txt

blablablai love pythongugugugugu  
blablablamacdonalds hamburgergugugugugu  
blablablayolo 4evergugugugugu
```

I already tried this algorithm, but it didn't work.

```
prefix = 'blablabla'  
suffix = 'gugugugugu'  
dest = ''  
with open('C:\listagem.txt', 'r') as src:  
    with open('teste.txt', 'w') as dest:  
        for line in src:  
            dest.write('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n'), suffix))
```

I am using python 3.2.3 on windows XP.

Comment: Did the script raise an exception?
How did it fail exactly?

Comment: How exactly does your code fail?

Comment: I tested your code and it works with me. You must be doing something else wrong that is not in your code, because the code that you posted does just what it is supposed to do, although the `dest = ''` is unnessacary and should be deleted.

Comment: The problem is that teste.txt dont have the output that i need. It became all blanc when i run the .py

Comment: all i wanted to do was this:  
'for line in src:   
     editedfile = line.write("blablabla"+line+"gugugugu")'

but if i do this i receive:
AttibuteError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly file, but the filename is the problem. See [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928789/strange-path-separators-on-windows).

Change your path like so:

```
with open('C:\\listagem.txt', 'r') as src:
```

..or using [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
with open(r'C:\listagem.txt', 'r') as src:  # r'raw string' ignores backslashes
```

..or you can maybe just use forward slashes - if this works, I'd recommend it (as backslashes are a pain):

```
with open('C:/listagem.txt', 'r') as src:
```

Also note that your sample input file appears to contain trailing whitespace. In your supplied data, there is two spaces after the `i love python`, thus your output looks like so:

```
{prefix}i love python  {suffix}
```

This might have been introduced in your Stackoverflow question, rather than the original file.

Comment: both files are opening, the real problem is that i cant get my output on teste.txt as a should

Comment: @user1634295 Oh, what output are you getting in `teste.txt`? Nothing?

Comment: @user1634295 Great \o/ Any idea what the problem was?