# Python - Numbers change when included in a directory string

Tags: python, string, directory, numbers

I have searched online and can't seem to find any other instances of this. Why does 2015 become x815 and how do I remedy this?

```
>>> os.chdir("N:\PRTR\Weekly Estimate\2015")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    os.chdir("N:\PRTR\Weekly Estimate\2015")
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'N:\\PRTR\\Weekly Estimate\x815'
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928789/strange-path-separators-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `\x` is the escape sequence that means the next two characters are interpreted as hex digits.

So you will have :

```
>>> '\2015'
'\x815'
```

And for get ride of that you need to escape `\` :

```
>>> print '\\2015'
\2015
```

Comment: If you dont want to escape everything you can just use raw_string, `print r'\2015'`

Comment: @lapinkoira Yes its another way!

Comment: Wow, it seems pretty obvious now... Thanks guys!!

Comment: @JackSellers Welcome! you can also tell this to community by vote accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in Python, "\" is an escape character in strings, and all special characters are created by a "\" followed by one or more other specific characters.  For example, `"\n"` in a string is a new line character.

As it happens, the "\" followed by three digits indicates a three digit octal character.  `"\201"` happens to correspond the the octal character �, which, to a terminal that can't print it, may come out as the hexadecimal number `x81`.

To avoid this, make your string a raw string by putting the letter `r` in front, outside the quotes, like this

```
print r'N:\PRTR\Weekly Estimate\2105'
```

The `r` will make Python interpret the string exactly as you entered it, ignoring all special characters and escape sequences, and you will get the result you want.

Comment: What text editor? :) I guess you mean [text terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Text_terminals). FWIW, `\201` == `\x81` is considered a control character in some [8-bit extensions to ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#8-bit), but some [code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) assign a glyph to it.

Comment: oops!  You're absolutely right!  I was thinking of the terminal, and typed editor.  I had been awake for a very long time.  Fixed it.