# How to properly format a filepath on Windows when using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner Pandas users and when trying to read this CSV file with Pandas, it cannot find the file.

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv('D:\Python\datasets\tweets')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\amr.bibars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\amr.bibars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\amr.bibars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\amr.bibars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\amr.bibars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File D:\Python\datasets    weets does not exist: 'D:\\Python\\datasets\tweets'
>>> pd.read_csv('D:\Python\datasets\cars.csv')
  Unnamed: 0  cars_per_cap        country  drives_right
0         US           809  United States          True
1        AUS           731      Australia         False
2        JAP           588          Japan         False
3         IN            18          India         False
4         RU           200         Russia          True
5        MOR            70        Morocco          True
6         EG            45          Egypt          True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcrfx.png)

Comment: check if files exists in that path.

Comment: You error indicates the file does not exist. 
That could mean in that directory the file is really missing or the file path you provided is not well formatted. 
Be mindful in Windows backslash followed by `r, n, c, b, t` becomes an escape character.
Could also be a typo as well or even an "invisible character" in cases when you copy paste.
See this answer for more details regarding escape characters in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6928938/4847576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the file exists in that directory, it could be as you're using backslash, that `\t` from `\tweets.csv` has been interpreted as a tab character.

In Windows you need to be mindful when providing paths to Python with backslash.

As I pointed in the comment, `r, n, c, b, t` and others, preceded by a backslash will be interpreted as an escape character.

[Check the table in this section of the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for a complete list.

One of the ways to address that is to use raw strings by prepending `r` to your path string:

`path = r'D:\Python\datasets\tweets.csv'`

Comment: Thanks for your help i did remove t from the file name and rename it but still receiving the same error

Comment: @Baibars bummer, did you try with raw strings?

Comment: I did with path function and doesn't work but now I did use only r before the string and it works! :) pandas.read_csv(r"File path")